# How to skip some of the class fields while iterating by reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, reflection

I have classes those are strongly bound with the ASP.NET MVC view. 
Against their fields/properties ( columns ), I have to generate a unique name using Guid.NewGuid(). In this way, every time view would open , there would be new unique name against every control which is associated with specific field/column inside that class.

But, I would like to skip some of the properties while generating unique name. Because, those properties are either hidden inputs or place holders for other specific purpose. What could be the nice way? Should I apply custom attribute for this? During iteration of fields, I would simply skip those fields.

For example the class is "

```
public abstract class DashboardModuleCommonSettings
{        
    public int ForwarderId { get; set; }
    public int ClientSubsidiaryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsContentUpdateable { get; set; }
    public int? AfterTime { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Not Required to be iterated for generating unique name]
    public string ModuleSettingsPopupName { get; set; }

    [Not Required to be iterated for generating unique name]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Not Required to be iterated for generating unique name]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string CurrentLayout { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, a custom attribute would be a valid solution here.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to implement that in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full example of how you would use it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NotRequiredForUniqueNameAttribute : Attribute { }
```

The `NotRequiredForUniqueNameAttribute` is applied to the properties that you don't want to use, so your class becomes:

```
public abstract class DashboardModuleCommonSettings
{        
    public int ForwarderId { get; set; }
    public int ClientSubsidiaryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsContentUpdateable { get; set; }
    public int? AfterTime { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [NotRequiredForUniqueName]
    public string ModuleSettingsPopupName { get; set; }

    [NotRequiredForUniqueName]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [NotRequiredForUniqueName]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string CurrentLayout { get; set; }
}
```

Then later when you want to extract the properties that do not have that attribute, you can do something like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static string GenerateUniqueName(DashboardModuleCommonSettings dmcs)
    {
        var propInfos = dmcs.GetType().GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(
            p => p.GetCustomAttribute<NotRequiredForUniqueNameAttribute>() == null);

        string uniqueName = "";

        foreach (var propInfo in propInfos)
        {
            //Do something with the property info
        }

        return uniqueName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible ways to do so is to define your custom attribute and ignore a property if it has one assigned.

```
public sealed class SkipPropertyAttribute: Attribute
{  
}
```

And on your class:

```
public abstract class DashboardModuleCommonSettings
{        
    public int ForwarderId { get; set; }
    public int ClientSubsidiaryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsContentUpdateable { get; set; }
    public int? AfterTime { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [SkipProperty]
    public string ModuleSettingsPopupName { get; set; }

    [SkipProperty]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [SkipProperty]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string CurrentLayout { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the [`Attribute.IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find out if attribute is defined.

Comment: Ivan :  Of course using this approach , I can use Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags). But which binding flag should I use? Is there any binding flag telling about attribute in .NET reflection available?

Comment: So `Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags)` returns a `MemberInfo` (yes, a `PropertyInfo` *is* a `MemberInfo`) that you can supply as a parameter to `Attribute.IsDefined`

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here's the dirty version without flags.

```
public abstract class DashboardModuleCommonSettings
{
    public int ForwarderId { get; set; }
    public int ClientSubsidiaryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsContentUpdateable { get; set; }
    public int? AfterTime { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string __marker__ { get; }

    public string ModuleSettingsPopupName { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentLayout { get; set; }
}

public static class Extractor
{
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> VisibleProperties<T>()
    {
        foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if ("__marker__".Equals(p.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) yield break;
            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```